# Может ли андроид сливать буржуям инфу?

Tags: android, безопасность

Мой планшет порой живет своей жизнью, тоесть периодически сам по себе залазит в поисковик, лихо вбивает символы и слова даже порой на буржуйском, потом недолго тупит и отрубается. Я пишу книгу и меня немного пугает то что могут украсть мои идеи. Я хочу чтоб мой планшет сохранял историю поиска чтоб я мог отследить куда и что он там сливает. Люди добрые подскажите как с этим бороться. Я отключил все автообновления а ему пофигу он все равно сам постоянно возвращает все галочки наместо. Подскажите в общем как мне быть?:( Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может. И сливает. Это точно. Спасет только алюминиевая шапочка.

Ну если серьезно, то конечно может сливать. В этом [были замечены](http://www.electronista.com/articles/11/09/01/htc.may.be.tracking.imei.more.user.behavior/) некоторые аппараты от HTC. Нет оснований считать, что аналогичные трекеры не вживлены и в другие аппараты от других вендоров. Наиболее известный трекер это скандально известный [Carrier IQ](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier_IQ).

Способ лечения один: получение рута и вживление какой-нибудь кастомной прошивки типа [Cyanogenmod](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/), правда 100% гарантию все равно никто не даст.

Comment: У меня самый простецкий планшетный пк texet, TM-9738w android 4.0.3, версия ядра 3.0.8+sdu@alkotel     я далеко не программист но думаю как залить прошивку разберусь, только подскажите плиз где найти подходящюю для него...

Comment: @ВанечкаVansik вкурите [форумы](http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=366805&st=720) - если там ничего не найдете, то вам не повезло :)

Answer (score 2):

Разумеется теоретически ваш планшет (или телефон/телевизор/скороварка) может сливать ту или иную информацию кому-то еще. Случаи такие бывали (недавняя история с телевизорами от LG, например). Однако если кто-то вдруг захочет узнать ту или иную подноготную о вас, то вряд ли этот кто-то будет делать это таким  "изящным" образом как вы описали:

> периодически сам по себе залазит в поисковик, лихо вбивает символы и слова

Кроме того, вы пишете, что

> Я пишу книгу и меня немного пугает то что могут украсть мои идеи

если вас зовут не Пауло Коэльо, Фредерике Бегбедер  или хотя бы Виктор Пелевин, то никто ничего у вас воровать не будет - это просто никому не нужно. Более того, сбор информации о пользователях обычно производится с иными целями, нежели кража идей (это вообще довольно бесполезная деятельность по ряду причин)

Comment: Ха! Извиняюсь конечно за столь громкое восклицание, но еслиб Вы знал о чем моя книга я думаю мнение было бы обратнопропорциональным, так как в ней есть(будет) опубликован научный прорыв. Честно говоря я вслух о ней не говорю, опасаюсь за жизнь.

Comment: На вашем месте я бы беспокоился не о данных, а о самом девайсе. Вдруг его украдут?

Comment: @ВанечкаVansik да  не бойтесь вы, всем правда глубоко  на научные прорывы. Давайте угадаем - вечный двигатель (тесломания как вариант), вечная жизнь или очередное божественное откровение ? Я знаю одного дядечку(проффесор, кучка знаний) он двинулся на том что "нашел" абсолютно неподвижные точки пространства.

Comment: @ВанечкаVansik и вы меня, конечно, извините, но вот когда ваша книга произведет этот самый научный прорыв, тогда и можно будет об этом говорить, а пока довольно неосмотрительно разбрасываться такими громкими словами. Только на посмешище себя выставите как какой-нибудь Д. Попов или Бабушкин. Впрочем, воля ваша. Но же если у вас есть те или иные опасения на этот счет, то вы всегда можете отказаться от любых устройств, которые, по вашему мнению, могут передавать кому-то вашу информацию, и записывать свои мысли дедовским способом на бумаге (либо на компьютере без интернета в комнате с решетками)

Comment: Данный девайс лишь для связи с "внешним" миром,  записи я все делаю в ручную по старинке, разве что набором гелевых ручек. Но все же отдельное спасибо Barmaley за проявленное внимание и ссылочку.